# Assign filename into database

Tags: javascript, filenames, plupload

I am new to programming and made a `php form` with attachment (plupload).

My question is, which one holds the `fileName` value:

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, info) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(info.response);
    $('form#quoteRequest').append('<input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="' + obj.result.cleanFileName + '" />');
 });
```

**upload.php**

```
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : {"cleanFileName": "'.$fileName.'"}, "id" : "id"}');
```

Comment: $fileName should contains your file name, though the code extract seems insufficient to be sure of that... And I am not sure I really understand what you want to know by "Which one hold the fileName value".

Comment: i know $fileName contain my file name, thats why i return the value form upload.php to my form php. i just dont know which one contain $fileName value at uploader.bind.

Comment: Between php and js? It seems that uploader.bind the name by file parameter...